# Query for any person has any account of type x

Tags: mysql

Imagine I have two tables, Person and Account, a person can have accounts (type 1 and/or 2).
I'd like to get a list of people who have at least one type 1 account, and also get a list of people who don't have a type 1 account. I'm using Query #1 and #2 for this respectively but I think I'm doing something is wrong because the results do not match.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  `PersonId` INTEGER,
  `Name` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO Person
  (`PersonId`, `Name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Leo'),
  ('2', 'Natan'),
  ('3', 'Vera'),
  ('4', 'Julio'),
  ('5', 'Mary');

CREATE TABLE Accounts (
  `AccountId` INTEGER,
  `PersonId` INTEGER,
  `Type` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Accounts
  (`AccountId`, `PersonId`, `Type`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '0'),
  ('2', '1', '1'),
  ('3', '2', '0'),
  ('4', '2', '0'),
  ('5', '3', '1'),
  ('6', '4', '0'),
  ('7', '1', '0'),
  ('8', '2', '0');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM Person AS PD
LEFT JOIN Accounts AS AC ON AC.PersonId = PD.PersonId
WHERE AC.Type = 1;
```

| PersonId | Name | AccountId | PersonId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Leo | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Vera | 5 | 3 | 1 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM Person AS PD
LEFT JOIN Accounts AS AC ON AC.PersonId = PD.PersonId
WHERE AC.Type = 0;
```

| PersonId | Name | AccountId | PersonId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Leo | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | Leo | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Natan | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Natan | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Natan | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | Julio | 6 | 4 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5gmu6EN4UjZDqvyFgb5sSS/0)

Comment: Your fiddle is empty perhaps you didn't save it. Also in your data-set there are only two persons (2 and 5) with type=1 and share expected output/format.

Comment: 'get a list of people who don't have a type 1 account' - You need to check that persons do not have a type 1 account in your second query I suggest an EXISTS test

Comment: Also, do you want to exclude person who do not have any account i.e. show people with account type not as '1' but at the same time exclude people who have no accounts?

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` are the more suitable solutions for this requirement:

```
-- Account type = 1
SELECT p.* FROM Person AS p
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Accounts AS a
  WHERE a.PersonId = p.PersonId AND a.Type = 1
);

-- No type 1 account
SELECT p.* FROM Person AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Accounts AS a
  WHERE a.PersonId = p.PersonId AND a.Type = 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ad009977b86007941738667ffc3799a).